# Xcode 7 - How do I change the build string

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

In xcode 7 when you click on your project, there are only tabs for "Info" and "Build Settings" (no more "General" or anything else). How do I change the build string (not the overall version number)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the same screen in Xcode, click on the target for your project; you will see additional tabs and options there including "General".  Under the General tab you will see the Identity section where you can find the "Build" field.

Comment: Thank you. I had the inside left bar thing minimized.